# JGit create remote repository?

Tags: git, repository, jgit

I need to create a new remote repository (to gitolite) from JGit, is it possible?

I see clone remote and create local but nothing about create remote.

Comment: No, I don’t think so.

Comment: Is it possible to create a local repository and add a remote?

Answer (score 0):

in Cgit you need to have following command. If you can use regular git following will work..

```
git remote add origin ssh://host.example.com/repo.git
```

Comment: from jgit api RemoteConfig