# JGit - Github - Create Remote Repository?

Tags: github, jgit

Like title says, is there a way to remotely create a repository on Github through JGit on my local machine? There is an identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468376/jgit-create-remote-repository) that is 9 years old but I was hoping support for it had been added since then. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-opening-br) question that details how it can be done through CLI.

I would like to avoid having to do it through CLI (or the hub tool) just so I don't have to handle external calls in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found a Java library that had better support than JGit for configuring remotely, switched over to this: https://github-api.kohsuke.org/

Comment: These are two complementary things, JGit is for using Git via Java in general, github-api focusses on interfacing with Github. So for a full-blown application where you use Git locally and interact with Github you will likely end up using both.